# Unicode characters in Javadoc

Tags: eclipse, unicode, javadoc

In my Eclipse project, source files use UTF-8 and I have no problem to use e.g.

```
ε (epsilon)
```

in a Javadoc comment fo a source file. However, when I generate the Javadoc (Project - Generate Javadoc), the epsilon character isn'T properly displayed - how to fix this?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: How is it displayed? `Îµ` or `�`?

Comment: it's the first one, so `Îµ`

Comment: As a workaround, you can use HTML numerical entities in plain ASCII. In this case, ε is `&#949;` .

Comment: Bananeweizen's reply helped me, also my prefered way over replacing everytinh with html entities :-) but thanks for the alternative solution :-)